# Change text depending on language

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using Wordpress with a language switcher to switch between various languages. Within the templates I'm using this piece of code to switch hard coded text.

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>
   This is english
<?php } else { ?>
   This is another language
<?php } ?>
```

I have a sidebar but it's created via various widgets so I can't put the same fix in place.

Using jquery, how can I target all the text within a specific div and replace it with something else?

If I put that jquery within the code above then that should work shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery/JS is Client, PHP is server, so that being said, there is one chance to inject PHP into  JavaScript, and that is at the run-time of the page. You can probably do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var language = '<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE?>';
    if (language == "EN") {
        $("#IDOFDIV").html("NEW HTML HERE");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked putting it within my PHP loop so didn't need the if statement in the jquery.