# how can I change placeholder text depend on language

Tags: php, wordpress, placeholder, multilingual

Hello I am newbie and I would like to ask how is it possible to change the placeholder depend on language?. I have a multilingual wordpress site and I wrote this code on a .php file :

```
<form class="search" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" method="get">
   <fieldset>
       <span class="text"><input name="s" id="s" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo __('Search', 'alora'); ?>" />
       </span>
   </fieldset>
</form> `
```

I also tried this:

```
<form class="search" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" method="get">
   <fieldset>
      if (get_locale() == "en_US") {
         <span class="text"><input name="s" id="s" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo __('Search', 'alora'); ?>" />
         </span>
         }
      else {
         <span class="text"><input name="s" id="s" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo __('Search_el', 'alora'); ?>" />
         </span>
         }
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But with no luck. Can anyone please help me?.

I also read this post [Change text depending on language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404038/change-text-depending-on-language), but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo _e('Search_el', 'alora'); ?>" />
```

**Please use this..**

if above code not working than use..

```
printf(__('Search_el', 'alora'));
```